# How to access screen shots made in CI test on specific gitlab-runner

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to make screen shots of my app  in CI tests using specific runner (its working on my pc, its not "shared-runner").

Its a basic docker runner. 
I tried to pass `builds_dir` to runner config with full path `/home/myuser/mybuilds` but after successful test, the folder is empty. (it seems its relative to build, not the linux path)

The screenshots are probably to be taken but paths seem to be relative.:

```
app.browserWindow.capturePage().then(function (imageBuffer) {
            fs.writeFile('/home/myuser/mybuilds/page-full-path.png', imageBuffer)
        })
```

So how to access build folder after the build in docker?

**EDIT**
I could use `artifacts` like this:

```
app.browserWindow.capturePage().then(function (imageBuffer) {
    console.log("This test path");
    console.log(path.join(__dirname));
    var mypath = path.join(__dirname, '../..', 'testimgages', "test.png");
    fs.writeFile(mypath, imageBuffer)
})
```

and then in gitlab-ci.yml

```
mytest
  script:
  - mytests
  artifacts:
    paths:
    -testimages
```

and then download images from gitlab.com but is there a way to make it faster or local viewing without going to gitlab.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's on your server then you can just add something like:
`-v /some/local/path:/data/screenshots:rw`
to your docker run command. It will bind mount local dir on your server to /data/screenshots in container. Then all you save there will appear in local dir.

Comment: Problem is that i can't find the local path that contains the gitlab-runner builds. Any ideas?

Comment: use `docker diff <build_container_id>` to list all that changed in your container since you started it. After build you should see your results there. When you use agent container all results by default land in that container. You need to "extract" them to host. IMHO simplest way would be bind mounting dir from host. Update question with output of: `docker diff <container_id> | grep testimages` and `docker run` command that you use to start build container. Then I'll be able to provide exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add volume you could copy files using `docker cp`:

```
docker cp <containerId>:/data/screenshots /local/path
```

You can find your container id with `docker ps`.